# How to use this for loop in Django template?

Tags: python, django

This is my first post in the Stack Overflow. I have this loop which works perfectly fine in Python itself.

```
for i, j in enumerate(ls.split("/")):
    print i * " " + j
```

I want to implement same thing in the Django template. Here's what I thought I would do:

```
{% for i, j in enumerate(ls.split("/")) %}
{% i * " " + j %}
{% end for %}
```

But this doesn't work. I get **ls** variable from the views.py. `i and j` variable are made up while implementing for loop. Thanks

Comment: Questions on stackoverflow should be valuable for others. As such, you should do some research before asking and come up with a real question. Your question shows that you did not really read Django's template documentation. None of the examples look like this. It is stressed that you cannot do calculations in templates in those docs.

Answer (score 4):

You don't seem to have read any of the documentation about Django templates. You should do that before asking questions.

Django's template language is intentionally restricted. It is not Python. You can't make arbitrary function calls in it. That sort of thing must be done in the view, or possibly in a custom template tag.

Comment: It is possible to do in the views. But it is not possible to store the result of for loop in the variable and later call in the template, Is it? So turns out this is my only option.

Comment: I don't understand the comment. Of course it is possible to do the loop in the view, store the result in a list, and pass that into the template for iterating over. Alternatively, you might just want to do the split in the view, and in the template iterate over that using `forloop.counter` to work out how many spaces. *Or*, you might consider that multiple spaces are collapsed into one in HTML anyway, so use nested `ul`/`li` tags to format your items.

Comment: Okay. I have done the list comprehension stored the result in one variable. I am stuck in formatting now in the template.

Comment: Also, I haven't said that it's not possible to do for loop in the views.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should look like this:

```
{% for i, j in data_supplied_to_template %}
    {{ i * " " + j }}
{% endfor %}
```

Notice the `endfor` keyword and the double brace syntax for template substitution.

Now you have to put the data you need into the `data_supplied_to_template` variable which you hand to the template engine for rendering.

Some additional advice includes using better nanes for your variables (i, j are usually reserved for integers and indexes)

See the [template documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#std%3atemplatetag-for) for more info.

Comment: That's not correct! Doesn't work.

Comment: @user1881957: You're right. You code had several problems and I wanted to show you the necessary changes to the template syntax. Please note my edits, and study the examples and docs from the Django project. It's actually quite easy to work with once you've grasped the concept.